# How to auto click OK on JOptionPane when testing?

Tags: java, swing, testing, popup, joptionpane

In my program I am testing a button which when clicked throws up a JOptionPane window in the application.

However when this window pops up it expects the user to click OK which means that the test can't continue unless the window is manually closed down.

I want to be able to close this window programmatically when it appears within my test or prevent these JOptionPane windows from popping up at all for this test.

Answer (score 3):

What I typically do in such case is to make sure the UI does not appear in my test. Just to illustrate this with some code. Let's say the dialog is triggered somewhere in an `Action`

```
public class ActionWithUI extends AbstractAction{

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
    //... do some stuff
   int result = JOptionPane.show... //show the dialog
   //do some other stuff based on the result of the JOptionPane
  }
}
```

I would then refactor my code so that the showing of the `JOptionPane` is in its own separate method.

```
public class ActionWithUI extends AbstractAction{

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
    //... do some stuff
   int result = askUserForInput();
   //do some other stuff based on the result of the JOptionPane
  }

  int askUserForInput(){
    return JOptionPane.show...
  }
}
```

Now in my test, I can test a custom version of that action where I override the `askUserForInput` method and just return the "OK" (or "Cancel", ... ) option. That will avoid any clever tricks in my test and keeps my code readable.

Another approach I sometimes use is not calling `JOptionPane.show` directly, but rather make sure my class accepts in its constructor a delegate class for showing such dialogs. In my test, I can then insert a mock instead of the real class, and intercept the call to the UI.

Of course, both of these approaches do not actually test whether the `JOptionPane` is correctly shown. But seeing as that is a JDK method, I do not really feel the need to test this. And it is not like I am bypassing some business logic. I just got rid of a `JOptionPane.show` call.

If none of these are an option, I normally use a listener attached to the `DefaultKeyboardFocusManager`. When the component which has the focus changes, I see whether it is the `JOptionPane` (using the Swing hierarchy) and dispose of it. This turns out to work quite well, but still not 100% reliable. Therefore (and certainly for new code), I try to stick to one of the two previously outlined approaches

Comment: The problem I see with this, is you've potentially changed the state of the application you are testing...possibly invalidating the test...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think that simply searching for an OK button and hitting it is quite useless as well. Note that in my approach, you could still visualise the contents of the `JOptionPane` if needed with some more refactoring. You just wouldn't show it in a blocking modal dialog

Comment: IMHO You shouldn't be changing the state of application just for testing, your also introducing code into the code base that will be included in production. While this example is rather simple, I'm sure you and I know that this isn't reality in a complex application...

Comment: Let us conclude that there is no "best solution" and there are pro's and con's to every approach. I agree with all your points, and I have test where I use similar approaches. And I also have tests where I bypass the UI as described above, and decided that the pro's outweighed the cons

Comment: :) Agreed. Every situation is contextual ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic ways to overcome this issue.  Both require you to be able to find the button.

This will require to be able to use a second `Thread` to find the window/dialog and walk it's container to find the button...

Depending on how your tests are set up will depend on how much additional work you might need to go through.  The UI should be operating within the Event Dispatching Thread, if your tests are running in the same thread, then you will need to use separate `Thread`, as the `JOptionPane` will block the EDT (in a special way), making it impossible for your code to run until the option pane is closed.

If your tests are already running in a separate `Thread`, then you have a little more capability...

This is a very simple example.  It initialises a `JOptionPane` within the context of the EDT, but has methods that are running in the main thread which find and execute the "OK" button of the message dialog.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FindButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is message dialog", "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        JDialog frame = waitForDialog("Message");
        System.out.println("Found window " + frame);
        if (frame != null) {
            final JButton btn = getButton(frame, "OK");
            System.out.println("Found button " + btn);
            if (btn != null) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn.doClick();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public static JDialog waitForDialog(String title) {

        JDialog win = null;
        do {
            for (Window window : Frame.getWindows()) {
                if (window instanceof JDialog) {
                    JDialog dialog = (JDialog) window;
                    System.out.println(dialog.getTitle());
                    if (title.equals(dialog.getTitle())) {
                        win = dialog;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (win == null) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } while (win == null);

        return win;

    }

    public static JButton getButton(Container container, String text) {
        JButton btn = null;
        List<Container> children = new ArrayList<Container>(25);
        for (Component child : container.getComponents()) {
            System.out.println(child);
            if (child instanceof JButton) {
                JButton button = (JButton) child;
                if (text.equals(button.getText())) {
                    btn = button;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (child instanceof Container) {
                children.add((Container) child);
            }
        }
        if (btn == null) {
            for (Container cont : children) {
                JButton button = getButton(cont, text);
                if (button != null) {
                    btn = button;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return btn;
    }

}
```

This example uses the `doClick` method of the `JButton` to simulate a clicking of the button.  You could use the `locationOnScreen` information from the button and `java.awt.Robot` to physically click the button. but this just seemed simpler.

You could also take a look at [Jemmy](https://jemmy.java.net/) which is a utiliy library designed to make it easiert to test Swing (and JavaFX) based applications...

Comment: I would say that your `waitForDialog` must also be called on the EDT as it works with Swing components. And if you do that, you are screwed... .

Comment: @robin the problem is, JOptionPane is blocking. You can't use waitForDialog on the EDT, cause it itself is blocking (see the Thread.sleep), so we have a catch 22. As we're not modifying the state of the UI its a "little" safer, but you could still run into a race condition, but seen as we're continuously checking the state it becomes less of an issue. If you're really worried, you might be able to use invokeAndWait, but my concern would be the fact the the JOptionPane is blocking the EDT (in its own special way), which could prevent it from ever returning

Comment: The benefit of this approach is that you don't need to place the application into "test" mode, which means when testing, you are testing the actual program as it would run in the wild, producing a more accurate test state.

Comment: And what I propose is rather lightweight, and the part you skip is a really thin UI layer which I find acceptable. I also think that in my approach the test remains readable, while your approach adds a lot of code. And to conclude ... I haven't tested this out in code but I think with the `SecondaryLoop` mechanism introduced in JDK7, you might be able to dispose of the dialog on the EDT (although I doubt that having a second EDT and accessing the dialog from it is more safe then your approach)

Comment: @robin Firstly, I'm not introducing anyone into the application to be tested that wouldn't be there in production which makes the test more void - IMHO. I'd also prefer to use a deteicated library, like Jemmy to perform these task. Testing Swing is series of compromise as the UI becomes more complex. One of the test frames I played around with actually had a "dialog callback" mechanism, actually found it annoying on the long run, but it did deal with the unexpected

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `JDialog` from a `JOptionPane` object. Then, create a `timer` to run for the time you want( exemple 1min) , and dispose the `dialog` once it has finished. Then, retrieve the chosen value from your `JOptionPane` object, making sure to account for an uninitialized value if the dialog was disposed by your timer.

```
    final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(......., JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(.....);
    Timer timer = new Timer(you_time, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            dialog.dispose();
        }

    });
    timer.start();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.dispose();
    Integer choice = (Integer) (pane.getValue() == JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE ? JOptionPane.OK_OPTION : pane.getValue());
```

Comment: This would require you to know that the application is running in "test mode" which changes the state of the program, changing the way it works and running the risk of invalidating the test...